# What type of aws cdk role principal type do I use for a cross account role arn?

Tags: aws-cdk

I need to replicate this in python cdk (let a role from another account assume this role)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "redshift.amazonaws.com",
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1234:role/otheraccountrole"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Do I use ArnPrincipal or AccountPrincipal in the example below?

```
iam.Role(
    self,
    "thisaccountrole",
    assumed_by=iam.CompositePrincipal(
        iam.ServicePrincipal("redshift.amazonaws.com"),
        iam.???Principal("arn:aws:iam::12345:role/otheraccountrole")
    ),
    managed_policies=[...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `ArnPrincipal` since this implements `IPrincipal`. That enables you to pass the ARN of the role.
See also the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_iam.ArnPrincipal.html) of the class for more information.

Comment: When I looked up "aws" the docs called it "account principal", thats what confused me

Comment: Yes, it is quite burdensome to keep up with the nomenclature! Glad I could help.